# Notice: Undefined index: txtP1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Encuesta\CapturaDatos.php on line 2

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Me apareceré ese error con cada variable, ya verifique si el nombre coincide 'txtP1' con el del formulario, ya que busco guardar los datos del formulario en la base de datos. He encontrado algunas soluciones a este problema con isset pero no me comprendido como aplicarlo al codigo. Les agradecería mucho.

Notice: Undefined index: txtP1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Encuesta\CapturaDatos.php on line 2

```
<?php
$Pregunta1=$_POST['txtP1'];
$Pregunta2=$_POST['txtP2'];
$Pregunta3=$_POST['txtP3'];
$Pregunta4=$_POST['txtP4'];
$Pregunta5=$_POST['txtP5'];
$Pregunta6=$_POST['txtP6'];
$Pregunta7=$_POST['txtP7'];
$Pregunta8=$_POST['txtP8'];
$Pregunta9=$_POST['txtP9'];
$Pregunta10=$_POST['txtP10'];
$Pregunta11=$_POST['txtP11'];
$Pregunta12=$_POST['txtP12'];
$Pregunta13=$_POST['txtP13'];
$Pregunta14=$_POST['txtP14'];
$Pregunta15=$_POST['txtP15'];

require("conexion.php");
$sql="insert into encuesta (Pregunta1,Pregunta2,Pregunta3,Pregunta4,Pregunta5,Pregunta6,Pregunta7,Pregunta8,Pregunta9,Pregunta10,Pregunta11,Pregunta12,Pregunta13,Pregunta14,Pregunta15) values 
('$Pregunta1', $Pregunta2, '$Pregunta3', '$Pregunta4', '$Pregunta5', $Pregunta6, '$Pregunta7', '$Pregunta8', '$Pregunta9', $Pregunta10, '$Pregunta11', '$Pregunta12', $Pregunta13, '$Pregunta14', '$Pregunta15',)";
$resultado=mysqli_query($miconexion,$sql);  
if($resultado=="true"){
    echo "Se realizo el registro...<br>";
}
else{
    echo "No se realizo ningun registro...<br>";
    echo $sql;
}
mysqli_close($miconexion);
?>
```

Comment: Compañero Seria bueno que incluyeras los archivos previos, como el html, ya que puede haber un error en como estés enviando los datos, el method en el form, un value que lleve el boton del submit o si trabajas con objetos; para revisar cual de estas opciones puede ser incluye el archivo del formulario y si interactúan otros antes de llegar a ese.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Antes de asignar a variables lo que recibes por el metodo `$_POST` tendrias que verificar que esten defininas. Ejemplo:

```
if(isset($_POST['txtP1'])){
 $Pregunta1=$_POST['txtP1'];
}
```

Tendras que hacerlo para todo lo que recibes por `$_POST` de esta manera evitaras este error.

Te puede interesar leer mas sobre `isset()`

[isset() PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

Comment: Habia encontrado esa manera de colocarlo pero me dice que la variable esta indefinida

Notice: Undefined variable: Pregunta1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Encuesta\CapturaDatos.php on line 7

Comment: Comenta la linea donde tienes la variable $pregunta1 y me dices que pasa

Comment: <?php
//$Pregunta1=$_POST['txtP1'];
if(isset($_POST['txtP1'])){
 $Pregunta1=$_POST['txtP1'];
}

Asi lo tenia anteriormente, no se si a eso se refiere?

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que comentes la primer linea en dónde tienes la primer variable dónde te arroja el error, esto hará que el script de php se siga ejecutando, esto es para ver si te marca error en las demas variables,